# Customize the Payload content of push notification, when application in Background mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, payload

I am implementing apple push notification into my app and i am getting the notification properly. But i have faced some problem, when the notification arrives into the application in background mode. From the server side, they are sending the notification in the format of

```
                    a/a/The new deal is added/someText/a
```

But i want to customize the payload message in the notification bar, ie) i want to display the message of **"The new deal is added"**. So how can i customize the payload of content in the notification bar when the application in the Background state?.

So please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the only way to change the message send via a push notification before it gets displayed is using the "localization" mechanism.

Have a look at the Apple's documentation about "Localized Formatted Strings":
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21

I'm not really sure this is what you are trying to achieve.

In my opinion, if you wan't to display different message/data wether your app is in background or in foreground, you should change the data sent via the push notification.

Something like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Message displayed when app is in background"
    },
    "foreground_alert" : "Another message or data used when app is in foreground"
}
```

When your app is in background, the content of "alert" will be displayed automatically.

When your app is in foreground, you will have to implement [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a) to catch and handle the incoming notification (and display the content of "foreground_alert" by example)